# apache2 incomprehensible https redirect

Tags: apache-2.2, web-server, virtualhost, website

I've got a question about apache2 and Virtualhosts.

I declared some  in my /apache2/sites-available/ownsites
in order to get access via different domains and subdomains, for example:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.domain1.de
    ServerAlias domain1.de
    DocumentRoot /var/www/domain1/
    ServerAdmin myemailaddress.de
    <Directory />
            Order deny,allow
            deny from all
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/domain1>
            Options -Indexes -FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride all
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.domain2.de
    ServerAlias domain2.de
    DocumentRoot /var/www/domain1/
    ServerAdmin myemailaddress.de
    <Directory />
            Order deny,allow
            deny from all
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/domain2>
            Options -Indexes -FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride all
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

everything works fine, I can access to the different domains and subdomains.
But the I enable ssl in order to get secure access to my mail-webaccess

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    SSLEngine On
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/certs/zarafa-ssl.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/certs/zarafa-ssl.key

    ServerName www.webaccess.domain1.de
    ServerAlias webaccess.domain1.de
    DocumentRoot /path/to/zarafa-webaccess/
    ServerAdmin myemailaddress.de 

    #rewrite rule for https  access
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
    RewriteRule (.*) https://webaccess.domain1.de [R]


    <Directory />
            Order deny,allow
            deny from all
    </Directory>
    <Directory /path/to/zarafa-webaccess/>

            Options -Indexes -FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride None
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>


</VirtualHost>
```

Also this access works fine, including the rewrite, if I try to access only with http

But the incomprehensible thing is, that now if I try to access to my main domain with https: https://www.domain1.de , I am redirected to the apache2-standard-index.html "It work's", even if I delete it.
Further my other domain www.domain2.de is redirected to my first domain, if I try to access with https: https://www.domain2.de  -> http://domain1.de

Maybe is there any other file from apache2 exits where former RewriteRules are saved, when I tried some RewriteRules out?

If I declare other  rules in order to define an other behaviour, there is no difference.

Does anybody had the same problem or has an idea how to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond

> **HTTPS**
>
> Will contain the text "on" if the connection is using SSL/TLS, or "off" otherwise. (This variable can be safely used regardless of whether or not mod_ssl is loaded).

Basically, if the connection is not using HTTPS the URL is *statically* rewritten to `https://webaccess.domain1.de`. Requesting `http://webaccess.domain1.de/dir/file.txt`? Nope, request rewritten to `https://webaccess.domain1.de`.

But this is a stupid rule to have since the VHost it occurs in is locked to port 443, so it will never be hit by a connection that is *not* HTTPS. Take this config out of the `*:443` config and put it in the relevant `*:80` config file.

Better yet, [refer to this](http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RewriteHTTPToHTTPS) and use this:

```
RewriteEngine On
# This will enable the Rewrite capabilities

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
# This checks to make sure the connection is not already HTTPS

RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]
# This rule will redirect users from their original location, to the same location but using HTTPS.
# i.e.  http://www.example.com/foo/ to https://www.example.com/foo/
# The leading slash is made optional so that this will work either in httpd.conf
# or .htaccess context
```

Need to find other rule definitions? Look for .htaccess files.

```
find /path/to/zarafa-webaccess/ -name '.htaccess'
```

Comment: yeah you were right, there the rewrite rule makes no sense. I put it in the *:80 file and defined every *:80 rule same as *:443 rule with rewrite to http: and now it works